# Maven Axis Generated classes are not usable in project

Tags: java, maven, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

Got some issues with axis generation from wsdl

Once generated, classes are not visible eclipse /target folder (I can see them in a terminal...)

I cannot include them and use them.

I guess I'm missing something here, axis and soap are such a pain...

The project jar contains the generated classes, I can add it to build path manually and that works.
If I'm including the maven module in another module, maven complains "

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate 1</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <packageName>com.test</packageName>
                <wsdlFile>path.to.wsdl</wsdlFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin is putting the JAR in a non standard place - this is why maven complains when you try in add it as a dependency.

Can you see the JAR being installed into your local maven repo?

Comment: No I can't see the jar in the maven repo, only in /target.
My other maven modules also generate their jars in /target, so i'm confused.. Does axis generation require another maven plugin in order to obtain a correct jar ?

Comment: It's been a while, so bear with me, as far as I remember axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin only generates Java source files and it does this during maven's generate-source phase - you should see these files under target/generated.  If you then run mvn clean install you will get a JAR but it will not pickup the source files under target/generated. Try playing around with the outputDirectory attribute of the plugin so that the source files are output into a directory that maven will pickup during the compile phase.

Comment: update : I see the jar in my m2 repo. (I was looking under the wrong folder)
but it can't be usable across maven modules..

Comment: Check the structure of the JAR compared to other maven JARs - I suspect that if the classes are held under generated then it isn't a legal maven JAR